# XmlSerializer C# array-like without wrapping collection-element

Tags: c#, xml, xml-serialization

I'm trying to parse a external XML file using the XmlSerializer in C#, the source XML looks something like this:

```
<product>
  <id>71464280-6d57-49de-ba26-35c9919d808d</id>
  <name>Random Product</name>
  <property name="color">Blue</property>
  <property name="country">SE</property>
  <property name="brand">Fancy Brand</property>
</product>
```

I'm trying to get this to match to a C# class and the problem is the "property"-elements, first I though of them as an list/array, but I did not manage to parse them without having a wrapping element like .. in the source, then I started to think that they might be properties on the class, like this:

```
 public class ProductXml
{

    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Property")]
    public string Color { get; set; }

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Property")]
    public string Country { get; set; }

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Property")]
    public string Brand { get; set; }
}
```

Is a class like this was to be serialized it would not render since there's multiple "property" elements.

Anyone knows how I should approach this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Turns out this was quite simple, just needed to make sure that the element name of the list-property matched the element name of the "Property"-class.

I found this out using this great utility https://xmltocsharp.azurewebsites.net/

```
[XmlRoot(ElementName = "product")]
public class Product
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "id")]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "property")]
    public List<Property> Property { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName = "property")]
public class Property
{
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [XmlText]
    public string Text { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Right solution, wrong explanation. The XmlElementAttribute is not only renaming the Items, in case of Collections it also 'flattens' the collection. Without this Attribute, the collection itself would get a Tag first, and the inner items would be one xml-level deeper. Be aware of, you have two different things called property, a Property and a Type-name. With XmlElement, you skip the propertyname, and set the typename( Name of an Item). The XmlRoot-Tag on property is useless, because this is not the root of an xml-document.

Answer (score 0):

This is how you could do it:

> ```
> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
> <product>
>   <id>71464280-6d57-49de-ba26-35c9919d808d</id>
>   <name>Random Product</name>
>   <property name="color">Blue</property>
>   <property name="country">SE</property>
>   <property name="brand">Fancy Brand</property>
> </product>
> ```

```
public class Product
{
    public string ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Color { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }
    public string Brand { get; set; }

    public Product(XElement element)
    {
        ID = element.Element("id").Value;
        Name = element.Element("name").Value;
        List<XElement> properties = element.Elements("property").ToList();
        Color = properties.Where(x => x.Attribute("name").Value == "color").First().Value;
        Country = properties.Where(x => x.Attribute("name").Value == "country").First().Value;
        Brand = properties.Where(x => x.Attribute("name").Value == "brand").First().Value;
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        XDocument doc = XDocument.Load("xml.xml");
        XElement productElement = doc.Descendants("product").First();
        Product product = new Product(productElement);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another method to get individual property values

```
    public class ProductXml
    {

        public Guid Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        private string Color { get; set; }
        private string Country { get; set; }
        private string Brand { get; set; }

        [XmlElement(ElementName = "Property")]
        public List<Property> property
        {
            get {
                return new List<Property>() {
                    new Property() { Name = "color", Text = Color},
                    new Property() { Name = "country", Text = Country},
                    new Property() { Name = "brand", Text = Brand},
                };          
            }
            set {
                foreach (Property prop in value)
                {
                    switch (prop.Name)
                    {
                        case "color" :
                            Color = prop.Text;
                            break;
                        case "country":
                            Country = prop.Text;
                            break;
                        case "brand":
                            Brand = prop.Text;
                            break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "property")]
    public class Property
    {
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "name")]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        [XmlText]
        public string Text { get; set; }
    }
```